# Webstorm adding script file to html page get unresolved variable or type error

Tags: webstorm

I'm getting **unresolved variable or type error** each time i tried to **include a .js file to my html** page,

is there any way to solve this error ?

[image]

Also i noticed when i **include a .css file it's auto complete the path** for me, but **not completing for any .js file i add**, is there any way to make it auto complete the path for my files ?

***UPDATE***

I have attached my language injections screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have some language (javascript?) injected into the src attribute value for some reason. Do you have any custom language injections configured? Check Settings/language injections

Comment: I have attached my language injections screen

Comment: not sure how your custom injections (the ones of 'global' type) are defined... Most probably it's 'xml: script/@src' that it causing the issue. Try disabling it